# Native SQL Queries in NHibernate transaction

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, transactionscope

Short and sweet:

1. Should I always flush a `SessionScope` before making any native SQL query in my application?

   I guess the answer is 'yes' because NHibernate implements caching, so maybe changes made are still not in the DB so the query would get inconsistent results.
2. How is the correct way to make those queries in the same transaction of the current active one in NHibernate?

   This is important because I could get deadlocks in my business logic.

Further documentation about both questions would be appreciated too!

Comment: This should answer your questions http://stackoverflow.com/a/10657698/1236044

Answer (score 1):

(I assumed that by "flushing" you're mentioning `ISession.Flush()`):

1. The quick answer is: It depends on your flush mode, if it's Never you will have to flush the session yourselves, but if it's Auto, NHibernate will flush before issuing the query.
2. There are two ways to execute native SQL queries with NHibernate. One is to use NHibernate's own native SQL support like using named query or `ISession.CreateSQLQuery()`. Other is to use NHibernate `ITransaction.Enlist()`. However, I'm not sure if executing a DbCommand using `Enlist()` will flush the session.